# How to detect click event of connected Bluetooth peripheral device (Selfie stick)?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have Selfie stick connected to my phone. I am able to find device ID using below code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

  //The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                //Device is now connected
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED" + device, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         }
    };
```

My question is how I can detect button press/click event of this connected peripheral device?

Help in form of code snippet/tutorial/comments is highly appreciable.
Thanks!!!

EDIT:

When I press button of Selfie stick Volume + button listen to the event

Comment: did you got any solution for this,if yes please share it

Comment: @YogeshSeralia, yes i found the solution. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. It was very simple. Just override `onKeyDown()` method of Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Here `keyCode` is the event name returned.

Comment: do your app uses default camera app for taking images or you have implemented custom camera to handle it?please let me know.

Comment: It's using default camera app but I think it will work in both cases

Comment: i have implemented custom camera app for doing this but can you please guide me on how can it use default camera app also?

Answer (score 1):

I have made slight modifications in your code. Please see if its helpful

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    IntentFilter a_filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, a_filter);
    IntentFilter b_filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
    **b_filter.setPriority(1000);** 
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, b_filter);
}
```

//The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            //Device is now connected
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED" + device, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    if (!Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON.equals(action)) {
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null) {
        return;
    }
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    // do something
    Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
    abortBroadcast();
    }
 };
```

Comment: It is not working. Still only Volume bar is shown (looks + button of volume is listening click from peripheral device)

Answer (score 0):

Using [accessibility service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService), You can achieve auto-click.

[Answer explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53498054/5096868), May be it's helpful to you !