# Use selfie stick to do something in a program

Tags: android

My app runs well in a pocket. It would be great to start recording with a bt button on a selfie stick. What intent or broadcast does the button trigger?

Comment: NOT sure but you can Start from `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` in your `Activity`. See if it get called.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440274/how-to-detect-click-event-of-connected-bluetooth-peripheral-device-selfie-stick